# Prevent {{image.url}} 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Working on a simple Angular app, where part of the functionality includes grabbing a set of images from a remote server. I'm then using `ng-repeat` to render these, but am getting a 404 on the initial page load as the browser can't find `<img src="myurl.com{{img.url}}"/>`

Have tried with `ng-cloak` and `ng-show` but these don't stop the browser looking for the image, they just hide the container.

Any help would be awesome...

Comment: do you know the possible combinations at code time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `ng-src`.

Please look more at [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Comment: Updated link for [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).